# Append with deep copy

Tags: python

I am trying to wrap my head around mutable object passed in function. In the code below, `solutionList` and `outSoln` return two different lists. From my understanding, the `append` function appends by reference. I tried to use `solutionList.append(sudoku[:])` and `solutionList.append(list(sudoku))` as done in other SO answers but it does not seem to work.
Is there a better way to do that assigning two global variables?

code:

```
def solve(options, onlyOneSoln=False):

    global sudoku
    global solutionList
    global outSoln

    if len(solutionList) > 5:
        return True

    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            # print("x: %s" %x)
            if sudoku[y][x]==0:
                for val in range(1,10):
                    if len(solutionList)>0 and onlyOneSoln:
                            break
                    if possible(val,y, x, sudoku,  options):
                        sudoku[y][x]=val
                        solve(options, prnt, onlyOneSoln)
                        sudoku[y][x]=0
                        # print_sudoku(sudoku)
                        # print("could not assign value -- backtracking")

                return


    solutionList.append(sudoku[:])
    outSoln =copy.deepcopy(solutionList)


sudoku = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6],
 [0, 4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0],
 [8, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0],
 [9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]


solutionList = []
outSoln= []
solve([''])

print("outsoln:")
print(outSoln)
print("\nsolutionList:")
print(solutionList)
```

output:

```
outsoln:
[[[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3], [7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6], [6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2], [8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5], [3, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 8], [4, 1, 2, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7], [5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 3, 4], [9, 7, 3, 5, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1]], [[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3], [7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6], [6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2], [8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5], [3, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 8], [4, 1, 2, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7], [5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 3, 4], [9, 7, 3, 5, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1]], [[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3], [7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6], [6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2], [8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5], [3, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 8], [4, 1, 2, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7], [5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 3, 4], [9, 7, 3, 5, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1]], [[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3], [7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6], [6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2], [8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5], [3, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 8], [4, 1, 2, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7], [5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 3, 4], [9, 7, 3, 5, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1]], [[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3], [7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6], [6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2], [8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5], [3, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 8], [4, 1, 2, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7], [5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 3, 4], [9, 7, 3, 5, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1]], [[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 5, 9], [1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 9, 8, 4, 3], [7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6], [6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2], [8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 5], [3, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 8], [4, 1, 2, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7], [5, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 3, 4], [9, 7, 3, 5, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1]]]

solutionList:
[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6], [0, 4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0], [8, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0], [9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6], [0, 4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0], [8, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0], [9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6], [0, 4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0], [8, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0], [9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6], [0, 4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0], [8, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0], [9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6], [0, 4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0], [8, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0], [9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6], [0, 4, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0], [8, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0], [9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]]
```

Comment: The answer is in your title: Use `copy.deepcopy()`

Comment: `sudoku[:]` is a shallow copy.

Comment: @Barmar That's the way i did it for `outsoln`. My question was more in the line of whether or not there was a way to this without having to create 2 global variables? Something like `solutionlist = copy.deepcopy(solutionlist.append(sudoku))` does not seem to work.

Comment: `sudoku[:]` is the copy that needs to be changed.

Comment: In case it matters or you're curious, the performance of `deepcopy` is horrendous. If you have a 2d list, `[x[:] for x in lst]` is much faster.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank! for the heads up.

Comment: @Jrakru56 That doesn't work because `append()` operates in place, it doesn't return the list. And even if it did, you've already modified it before passing it to deepcopy, so it's too late.

Comment: Are you sure you need to make a copy of the solution list?

Comment: This piece of code does the trick `solutionList.append(sudoku)
    solutionList = copy.deepcopy(solutionList)` . I am not sure why this is different from `solutionlist = copy.deepcopy(solutionlist.append(sudoku))`.

Comment: @Barmar I see! That answers my comment above. Thank you for the clarification.